# Android app to mute sounds for some, but not all, notifications

Tags: android, audio, notification

Can anyone recommend an Android app that will mute the sound for selected notifications, but still allow the default sound for other notifications?

Must work on Android KitKat.  Prefer [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis), but paid is okay.

If the app requires root or the Xposed Framework, that's okay as well... please just indicate that in the answer.

Prefer [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source), but it's not required.

Prefer [ad-free](/questions/tagged/ad-free), but it's also not required.

Comment: Didn't try any, but vaguely remember there were some. See my list: [Notification Settings](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_543): [XNotifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Taptigo.Xposed.XNotifications) can do that (in its paid version: "quiet hours per-app"; root+Xposed); [Notifications filter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tadevel.notification) seems to be capable of that, too ("Setup sound and vibration for every application"). Just picked 2 examples, there are more.

Comment: NotifyClean xposed module could do this with it's donation pack. Huge amount of customization are available with it.

http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.defim.apk.notifyclean